# Customizing contextual help for every page

Tags: contextual-help

How can i change the content of the help section for all of my admin pages?

I've removed a lot of the admin that won't be used, but i want to add information to the help section for the additional pages. Like the add new page for all my custom post types and different pages that are used in the plugins i'm using. So i can explain how to do things on the specific pages.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code in your functions.php file.

```
function example_contextual_help( $contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen ) {
    //echo 'Screen ID = '.$screen_id.'<br />';
    switch( $screen_id ) {
        case 'my_plugin_page_1' :
            $contextual_help .= '<p>';
            $contextual_help = __( 'Your text here.' );
            $contextual_help .= '</p>';
            break;
        case 'my_plugin_page_2' :
            $contextual_help .= '<p>';
            $contextual_help = __( 'Your text here.' );
            $contextual_help .= '</p>';
            break;
    }
    return $contextual_help;
}
add_filter('contextual_help', 'example_contextual_help', 10, 3);
```

To get the screen_id of the particular page, just uncomment the first line in the above function and check your plugin page's contextual help. Then add the screen id to the switch case like 'my_plugin_page_1'. Incase your plugin is a single page plugin (or few pages) then you could just do a if condition (any one would do) instead of the switch cases in the following manner.

```
if ( $screen_id == 'my_plugin_page' ) {
   $contextual_help .= '<p>';
   $contextual_help = __( 'Your text here.' );
   $contextual_help .= '</p>';
}
return $contextual_help;
```

Comment: Is this the simplest way? Is there no plugin or something. With this can i edit the help of all the pages i want to. How do i differentiate between each page? Is it based on what you put for case 'my_plugin_page_1'

Comment: Yup sorry I forgot to mention that.... I'll edit the answer so that it is more clear to you.

Comment: Does the above answer solve your issue? Or you still stuck?

Comment: I think it does, but i've only quickly tested it. I think it should be ok but i won't mark it as the right answer just yet, until i've done more just in case i need some more help. I will accept it soon though if it goes ok.